Discrepancy in Steady-State Error Calculation for Nonunity Feedback System

Problem Statement
For the system given:
$$G(s)=\frac{100}{s(s+10)}$$
$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s+5}$$
I need to find the steady-state error for a unit step input.
Solution 1: Unity Feedback Conversion

Convert to Unity Feedback:


Equivalent transfer function:
$$
G_e(s)=\frac{100(s+5)}{s^3+15 s^2-50 s-400}
$$


Calculate Steady-State Error:


Position error constant:
$$
K_p=\lim _{s \rightarrow 0} G_e(s)=-\frac{5}{4}
$$
Steady-state error:
$$
e(\infty)=\frac{1}{1+K_p}=-4
$$

Solution 2: Direct Calculation

Nonunity Feedback:


Error signal:
$$
E(s)=\frac{1}{s+\frac{100}{(s+10)(s+5)}}
$$


Calculate Steady-State Error:


Using the final value theorem:
$$
e(\infty)=\lim _{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{s(s+10)(s+5)}{s(s+10)(s+5)+100}=0
$$

Discrepancy:
The unity feedback conversion method results in a steady-state error of
−4, while the direct calculation method results in
0. I suspect the discrepancy arises from the feedback configuration and system type interpretation.
Question:
Why do these two methods yield different results, and which one is correct for determining the steady-state error in this nonunity feedback system?
Any insights or clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

There is an error \$G_e(s)=G(s)\cdot H(s)\$ open loop
For a unity feedback system, the steady-state error is derived from:
\$E(s)=\dfrac{R(s)​}{1+Ge​(s)}\$
with R(s)=1/s step input in a closed loop.
Now you can complete this for ;
ess = s→0 lim​  s⋅E(s)

When the closed-loop function for a system with feedback is
F(s)=G(s)/[1+G(s)*H(s)]
the "final value theorem" says that you have to find the value for the product s*F(s) for s=0.
(This theorem applies for unity feedback as well as non-unity feedback).
